# Any way to speed up Team System Web Access' first startup?

Tags: team-foundation-server, tswa, tsweb

Does anyone else experience really slow startup time the first time TSWA is accessed after an idle period? I'm considering running a task to get the page every minute or so just to keep things cached.. But this doesn't seem right. I know TSWA is an ASP.Net app but from what I understand it is also pre-compiled so that shouldn't be slowing it down. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Even precompiled ASP.NET apps have a nasty startup hit. Generally the more complex the app, the more painful the startup. Writing a script could help, but you are probably better off changing the application pool settings not to shut down every 1740 minutes, which is the default. I usually start with never and work my way down if there are problems.

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling the application pool idle time-out by setting it to "0" minutes.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771956(WS.10).aspx